# How to create a youtube video gallery using php

Tags: javascript, php, youtube, youtube-api

I want to create a youtube video gallery using php for my website.Below is a sample image

[image: Sample image of youtube video gallery]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.org](http://s-plugins.wordpress.org/youtube-channel-gallery/assets/screenshot-5.jpg?rev=660088))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YouTube Video Gallery Scheduling:**

http://codecanyon.net/item/youtube-video-gallery-scheduling/4489098

**Jquery youtube video gallery plugin:**

https://github.com/wheeziermoth/yt-video-gallery
[image]

Comment: Thanks.but i dont use cms to install plugin.Can you help me with some code samples

Comment: This a jQuery plugin, not a CMS plugin.